# Writing a shell script to obtain entries that contain a certain amount of integers?

Tags: shell, ls

I need help doing this I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

ls -l [0-9][0-9]*
```

I am trying to get all the entries with 2 integers in them.

says ls cannot access no such file or directory

Comment: `ls -l [0-9][0-9]*` works for me. i.e. to list files witch **begins** with two digits. Globbing should be anabled per default. Read more here http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob

Comment: says ls cannot access no such file or directory

Comment: _I am trying to get all the entries with 2 integers in them._ -- Did you try saying `ls *[0-9][0-9]*` instead?

Comment: yes but that gave me some directories with no numbers in them

Comment: It implies that it matched some directory names as well.  Say `echo *[0-9][0-0]*` instead.

Comment: got it i did what devnull said.. it didnt work the first time cuz i had a space between * and [. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ls -l | awk '{print $9}' | grep '[0-9][0-9]'
```

Or if you simply want to count them:

```
ls -l | awk '{print $9}' | grep '[0-9][0-9]' | wc -l
```